# PHP Contact Form with PHPmailer

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I want to create Contact form for my php project and I decided to use phpmailer so here is my code:

```
 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
 $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';
 $mail->Password = 'password';
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
 $mail->Port = 465;

 $mail->isHTML();
 $mail->Subject = 'Contact From My Friends';
 $mail->Body = <p>Message Body</p>;


 $mail->FromName = 'Contact';
 $mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com','name');
 if ($mail->send()) {
     echo "success"
 } else {
     echo "Failed";
 }
```

The problem I have is that when I try to send a message I receive:

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   [Troubleshooting PHPMailer Problems](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Also I disabled openssl on Xampp php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

I tried a lot of things but I don't know what is causing the problem. Please help me.

Comment: thank you for your edite

Comment: Click on the "Troubleshooting PHPMailer Problems" link and follow the "Enabling debug output" instructions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález never knew about the case (in)sensitive thing, been coding for years :). Still a good thing to keep things in sync though.

Comment: If you are following this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810669/unable-to-send-mail-through-google-smtp-with-phpmailer?rq=1, you should update your post with what you have tried already. There are a lot of different things mentioned in that post and your code, right now, doesn't resemble the examples given.

Comment: i changed every thing exactly same as things the topic says but i get error